# Open and edit XML file in web page

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, file-upload

Using ASP.NET and C# I'm looking for a way to open and edit an XML file via a web page.  A user needs to go to a web page, open an xml file that is stored on their local machine, and then make edits and save it back locally.

I'm not sure how to open the file.  Do I use the FileUpload control to let the user browse to the local file and then on a button event load the file into an XmlDocument?  I tried this and could not get it to load the file.  Once I have the file loaded I think I can build/edit nodes and data.

Not sure how to then save it back to an XML file on the local machine again.

Comment: You need to serve it as a download.

Comment: The file is always on the user's local machine, I can't host the file.

Comment: No; you need to serve the edited version for the user to download to overwrite the original local copy.

Comment: _"file is always on the user's local machine"_ - then forget about ASP.NET and investigate JS (jQuery etc).

Comment: I added some info to the original question to clarify what needs to happen. The user needs to go to a web page, open an xml file that is stored on their local machine, and then make edits and save it back locally.  Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do this in an `ASP.NET` web application I see the following process:

1) allow users to select a local file from their machine and then upload it on server and show its content in an edit box ( here you could also do nice things like allow drag and drop from windows explorer, there should be some JQuery / JS components ready out of the box to provide such feature );

2) once the file content is shown in the web page in a multi-line textbox ( ideally you would like to provide syntax coloring etc using specific web controls ), users can edit the content of it;

3) after changes are made, clicking on a save button the web page will start the download of the file from server to client, you can download the file with same name as it was uploaded if you stored that name somewhere, users will decide where to save the file.

This is the way I understand/see you can provide a functionality similar to what you have described from the top of my mind.

Comment: This seems to me more of what I'm looking for.  I'm still unclear on your #3.  The file gets uploaded and then read from the server and data placed into controls for edit.  Once edited in the browser, the user hits Save and what happens?  The edited data is parsed back into XML and uploaded with the same file name?  And re-downloaded to show the changes?  This application doesn't have to be pretty, its for internal users to manage a manufacturing product list.  Individual products with attributes like model number, size, color, etc.